# Get worksheet based on selected Index item in a ComboBox

Tags: c#, .net, combobox

I'm trying to select a Excel worksheet based on a selection made by users on a ComboBox element but this is the only solution I've and it's ugly:

```
using (var package = new ExcelPackage(existingFile))
{
    ExcelWorkbook workbook = package.Workbook;
    if (workbook != null)
    {
        if (workbook.Worksheets.Count > 0)
        {
            ExcelWorksheet currentWorkSheet;

            if (blYear.Text == "2010")
            {
                currentWorkSheet = workbook.Worksheets.First();
            }
            else if (blYear.Text == "2011")
            {
                currentWorkSheet = workbook.Worksheets[2];
            }
            else if (blYear.Text == "2012")
            {
                currentWorkSheet = workbook.Worksheets[3];
            }
            else if (blYear.Text == "2013")
            {
                currentWorkSheet = workbook.Worksheets[4];
            }
            else
            {
                currentWorkSheet = workbook.Worksheets.First();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's possible to get the selected Item index from the ComboBox and improve more my code? Otherwise I'll need to touch the code every time the Excel gets a new sheet and I don't want this. Any help? Advices? Solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the [ComboBox.SelectedIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindex.aspx) property.

```
int i = blYear.SelectedIndex;
currentWorkSheet = workbook.WorkSheets[i + 1]; 

//The VSTO library uses one-based arrays for some reason, and .SelectedIndex 
//uses the standard zero-based ones. Hence the "+ 1".
```

I can't test this myself at the moment but it was the first thing that came to mind.

---

As a side note for doing these kind of `if, else if, else if, else if...` statements all using the same object, you could use the [switch/case](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) statement instead.

Example:

```
switch (blYear.Text)
{
       case "2010":
           currentWorkSheet = workbook.Worksheets.First();
           break;
       case "2011":
           currentWorkSheet = workbook.Worksheets[2];
           break;
       case "2012":
           currentWorkSheet = workbook.Worksheets[3];
           break;
       case "2013":
           currentWorkSheet = workbook.Worksheets[4];
           break;
       default:
           currentWorkSheet = workbook.Worksheets.First();
           break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @hjalmar-z taking your suggestion I made my code and look like this: `int k = blYear.SelectedIndex == -1 ? 1 : blYear.SelectedIndex;
ExcelWorksheet currentWorkSheet = workbook.Worksheets[k];` practically is the same as you said before

Comment: Yes, I didn't think in switch/case way, thanks for that suggestion too

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
public class Form1 {

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
        Excel.Application oXL = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Open("C:\\your_path_here\\your_file.xls");
        oXL.Visible = true;
        foreach (Excel.Worksheet oSheet in oWB.Sheets) {
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(oSheet.Name);
        }

        ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
}
```